# C functions with : : (double colon) syntax?

Tags: c

I have come across this " :: " double colon syntax in many functions in a C file and I'm not at all sure what this is?!

My Googling results seems to say this is the GDB Scope Resolution Operator, although I haven't found many examples of this nor seen it mentioned before in C tutorials (it seems to appear a lot more in C++ source code..).

Also I've never yet used GDB.

Here is one example function from the C sourcecode I've found it in:

```
     Player :: Move (Pos *f, Pos *t)
{
    board->Move (f, t);
    board->Dump ();
    PaintBoard ();
    return 1;
}
```

So I'm grateful for some good help and explanation of this "::" operator in C.

My C knowledge is very basic and just now I do not yet understand what the "- >" operators mean but I hope to figure out these all these operators and pointer actions in these functions as I learn more C!

Comment: That looks a lot like C++ code to me, with the`->` operator as well

Comment: `::` is not valid in C. In C++, the `::` is used to declare class methods, e.g. `Player` is a class, and `Move` is a method.

Comment: @RowlandShaw: what do you mean "with the`->` operator as well"?

Comment: @RowlandShaw C has the `->` operator. Yet +1 for this piece of code looks like C++.

Comment: @Cornstalks I mean the combination of how it's being used, along with everything else screams C++

Comment: OK..thanks everyone for your helpful comments. I too,had seen the comment that the double colon was not C code,but I found it in a C file called chess.c (Written by Ashok Sreenivasan, TRDDC, Pune, India.  1993.  May be  distributed freely, provided this comment is displayed at the top.). So this code seems to be C++ code in a C file? I shall have to ignore this code now as I am currently trying to learn C and not C++ and this is just confusing me! Thanks for your helpful replies :-)

Comment: "I have come across this " :: " double colon syntax in many functions in a C file" -- No, you haven't. You've seen it in a C++ file. (I *hope* the file wasn't named with a `.c` suffix.)

Comment: @rpd: I wouldn't call it "C++ code in a C file". I'd call it a C++ source file that's incorrectly named with a `.c` suffix.

Comment: @Keith..yes I found it in a file named chess.c and this is quite confusing for me as I'm still learning C. Also it is quite mean of persons to down vote my question, which is quite sensible for someone still learning C programming as I am. Remember, it is tough to learn programming on your own and this forum should be supportive and not negative...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`::` is not C but is the C++ *scope resolution operator* (C++11, 3.3.6p2).

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator for more information.